# Get all unique values in array after validating content

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have this very simple array:

```
let result = ["doc1.rtf","doc2.rtf","test/doc4.rtf","test/doc4.rtf","test/doc6.rtf"]
```

I could find the unique occurrences by running something like.

```
let unique = [...new Set(result)];
```

Which will return me:

```
["doc1.rtf","doc2.rtf","test/doc4.rtf","test/doc6.rtf"]
```

But what I want to do is search the array for anything unique after filtering out the contents of anything up to a leading slash. So the array will look like this below before I filter out the duplicate `test/`

```
let filtered = ["doc1.rtf","doc2.rtf","test/","test/","test/"]
```

Thanks in advance. Is there a way to do above in one operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand the question correctly, but you can play around with `map`. For example:

```js
result.map(r => r.split('/')[0])
# ["doc1.rtf", "doc2.rtf", "test", "test", "test"]

result.map(r => r.replace(/\/.*/, '/'))
# ["doc1.rtf", "doc2.rtf", "test/", "test/", "test/"]
```

might yield what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To remove anything up to a leading slash you could use `map` with `split`:

```js
let result = ["doc1.rtf","doc2.rtf","test/doc4.rtf","test/doc4.rtf","test/doc6.rtf"];
result.map(i => i.split('/')[0]);
// ["doc1.rtf", "doc2.rtf", "test", "test", "test"]
```

And than look for unique elements

```js
let unique = [...new Set(result)];
//["doc1.rtf", "doc2.rtf", "test"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish the filtration in one pass by mapping each item of the array to a resolver, then using a Set for membership.

```js
const uniqMap = resolver => function uniqMapping(array) {
  const existing = new Set(),
    result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const item = array[i]
    const resolvedItem = resolver(item)
    if (existing.has(resolvedItem)) {
      continue
    }
    existing.add(resolvedItem)
    result.push(resolvedItem)
  }
  return result
}

let data = ["doc1.rtf","doc2.rtf","test/doc4.rtf","test/doc4.rtf","test/doc6.rtf"]

console.log(
  uniqMap(item => item.split('/')[0])(data),
) // [ 'doc1.rtf', 'doc2.rtf', 'test' ]
```